# Cycles render is different when rendering with GPU

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

I came across a problem which I couldn't find any solution through google. When I render with my GPU, I have a different render than with the CPU.

My CPU is an amd phenom 2 x4 965, the GPU is a R9 390 with blender 2.76
first is cpu second is gpu
I have sharp shadows with cpu and light is very dim with gpu, what could cause this problem?

CPU
[image: CPU]

GPU
[image: GPU]

Comment: Could it be that a feature not supported in GPU rendering is enabled?

Comment: Well i just had a look at the supported features page, and it says that HDR float isn't supported yet with opencl http://blender.org/manual/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html "OpenCL:
No support for HDR (float) textures at the moment.". In this scene there is an HDRI in use for the lighting. How can i circumvent this issue? Do i have to manually create the scene with a sun and what not?

Comment: or just use the CPU

Comment: too bad it's awfully slow

Comment: Try saving it in a different format? openexr supports 32bit float colour, png has 16bit colour.

Comment: how can i convert a 32 bit hdr to a half float openEXR? does  blender handle those?

Comment: I bought the card knowing that HDR images are not supported. I bought the card for the memory capacity and 'future-proofing'. But it seems to me that its a future that will never happen... The driver development is slow at AMD and many Blender features does not work on OpenCL. Currently looking for Nvidea alternatives. Can someone tell me if openEXR works instead of HDRI? Thanks.

Comment: update blender, if not fixed, report a bug to programmers!!!

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a HDRI lighting in my scene which is not yet supported in OpenCL. Anyone knows when it will be supported?

Well i just had a look at the supported features page, and it says that HDR float isn't supported yet with opencl

blender.org/manual/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html

"OpenCL: No support for HDR (float) textures at the moment.".