# CPU and OpenCL gives 2 different rendering result?

Tags: opencl

[image: CPU]

[image: OPENCL]

the 1st pic is made by cpu, the 2nd opencl. How do I make OPENCL work the same as CPU?

Comment: It depends on some things, particulalry the fact whether all the shaders / features you used [are actually supported with OpenCL](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/features.html) like SSS or HDRi map etc. Somewhat related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40341/cycles-render-is-different-when-rendering-with-gpu

Comment: Yes, OpenCL is pretty much experimental at this stage, not all features are supported yet. Some shaders don't work, it looks like you may be using translucency or sub surface scattering which may not be supported under OpenCL.